# How can I create a hotkey to play/pause Pandora on OS X?

Tags: macos, hotkeys, pandora

I'm on OS X and want to have a hotkey (e.g. Cmd-Opt-P) to play/pause Pandora.  I've used Butler to set one up for iTunes, but can't find a comparable solution for Pandora.  I'm open to any solution (including apps, AppleScripts, etc.) that would allow me to bind a hotkey to play/pause, and I'm willing to use a paid solution as well.  What can I do?

Solutions I've looked into and/or tried:

- [Pandora Boy](https://code.google.com/p/pandoraboy/): but the keyboard shortcuts don't seem to work for me, despite following the instructions [here](https://code.google.com/p/pandoraboy/issues/detail?id=94).
- The official Pandora One player: according to the comments on [this Pandora blog post](http://blog.pandora.com/pandora/archives/2009/09/pandora-one-get.html), it doesn't support hotkeys.

My system:

- OS X 10.6.6
- Each of the various truly-modern browsers
- Flash 10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Automator, select the "Service" template. Configure (at the top) the service to receive *no input* in *any application*. On the left in *Library » Utilities*, double-click the *Run AppleScript* action to add it to the service. Paste the following code:

```
tell application "PandoraBoy" to playpause
```

Press `Cmd-S` to save and name it "Play/Pause Pandora".

---

Open *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Services*, select "Play/Pause Pandora" from the list and click to its right so an input field appears. Press your desired shortcut.

Comment: This solution is perfectly valid and effective, though I want to mention that I'm not using it exactly as listed.  Rather than creating an Automator service and using system prefs to bind the hotkey, I'm using an AppleScript item in Butler, since it's slightly simpler and I have most of my hotkeys defined there.  I am using the AppleScript exactly as given above, which is why I'm leaving this as the accepted answer, but I wanted to make a note of the Butler option since it seems more straightforward.

Comment: @etlovett I launch most of my scripts using LaunchBar (instead of making them into Services), but I cannot assume that you're using a launcher, and you didn't mention Butler in your question.